# Can I set up a Paypal button where the sender pays the handling fee?

Tags: php, paypal

Normally Paypal button will charge fee from receiver, but I want to write PHP code for a Paypal button that when sender send money to someone, sender will pay PayPal fee. How can I do that?

Comment: PayPal can't send monkeys.

Comment: He's correct. We won't send monkeys to anyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I am aware there is no such option. You can work the amount backward and add it to the amount originally paid (if you are using some sort of shopping cart/form)
so if you are to receive $100 and paypal's commission is 2.5% + $0.3.
I would use a formula like $100 + (($100.3 / 0.975) * 0.25) + 0.3.
I am not sure if paypal charges the 0.3 for the 2.5% as well. So you might have to check that and update the formula.

Comment: Sure , thank. But i must to update formula when payapl change fee rate. i think this way not complete for me

Comment: Yes that unfotunately is a down side. But I don't see any other way unless paypal allows such a thing. As far I as I am aware the only method you can receive money where the payor is bearing the cost is if you receive it as a gift. [link]https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/Sending-and-receiving-money/How-can-sender-pay-the-Paypal-transaction-fees/td-p/508116?profile.language=en-gb[/link]

Comment: thank for reply, i will look for paypal button, may be i can found code that can charge fee from buyer.

Answer (score 1):

We currently only offer this option with our Adaptive Payments platform, where you can set the `feesPayer` to either party in a transaction under certain approved conditions.  For details, please see our [Pay API](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Pay_API_Operation/) documentation.
For a full overview of the capabilities of Adaptive Payments, please see our [documentation here](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/adaptive-payments/).

Unfortunately changing the fees payer is not currently available or Website Payments Standard or any of our other existing checkout products.

Whilst Ela's earlier suggestion might work in theory, our user agreement does not allow for a so called surcharge, so keep this in mind; https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/ua/useragreement-full

> **4. Receiving Money.**
>   **4.6 No Surcharges.** You agree that you will not impose a surcharge or any other fee for accepting PayPal as a payment method. You may charge
>   a handling fee in connection with the sale of goods or services as
>   long as the handling fee does not operate as a surcharge and is not
>   higher than the handling fee you charge for non-PayPal transactions.

Comment: but Adaptive Payments, sender must setting api user, pass, sign nature

Comment: That's correct. With Adaptive, setting the feesPayer to 'SENDER' is only allowed when the API caller is also the sender (called 'implicit payments'). That's the "under certain approved conditions" I was referring to.

Comment: If I have a business account and I make payments via the console, is it possible that I pay the fees rather than the receiver of the payment? I don't want to add the fee amount to the payment because then the amount received isn't as clear (eg: instead of the receiver getting notice that they received $10 which is what they expect, it will say something like $10.62).